# How to debug my random number guessing program?

Tags: java, random

I need my program to pick a number in between two numbers (min and max) that I had selected, then I have 5 tries to figure out which number he has in mind. But the problem is that computer doesn't really interpret the limits right - picked number is sometimes outside of the extremes. `min=3` `max=6` - Why do I get as a result the correct number is `7`?

The code is here:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Game1 {
         public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 

    int min = sc.nextInt();

    int max = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println("insert a number");

        int rand = min + (int)(Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1));

        for (int i = 0; i <=5; i++){

        int number = sc.nextInt();

            if (number == rand){

                System.out.println("congratulations! :D");
                break;
            }

            else if (i < number){

            System.out.println("The number is too big");

            }

            else if (i > number){

            System.out.println("the number is too small");

            }

            else{

            System.out.println("Try again");

            }               

            }

        }

 }
```

Comment: Check your conditions in else-if part first. why are you comparing i and number ?

Comment: typo `rand` instead of `number`

Comment: Another option instead using `Math` is using `Random`, which has an [`Random#nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt--) method.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your if statements that check the user's answers. You need to compare the user's input `number` to the random number `rand`. Instead you are comparing the loop counter `i` to the input.

Another issue is that your `for` loop performs 6 iterations, not 5. To fix this, change `i <= 5` to `i < 5`. This is because `i` starts at 0, not 1.

Lastly, to display the try again message, move it outside of the `for` loop. Then change the `break` to a `return` so that it isn't displayed when the answer is correct. Here are all of the fixes put together:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    int number = sc.nextInt();

    if (number == rand) {
        System.out.println("congratulations! :D");
        return;
    } else if (rand < number) {
        System.out.println("The number is too big");
    } else if (rand > number) {
        System.out.println("the number is too small");
    }
}

System.out.println("Try again");
```

Your random generation is fine - it seems to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/363732/5717792) post.